# Copy specific files and keep the subfolder structure

Tags: macos, finder, applescript, command-line, automator

I got a folder with a large amount of files with different suffixes in several sub folders.

My automator workflow works as follows:

1. Ask for Finder Items
2. Get Folder Contents (sub folder option checked)
3. Filter Finder Items (for a specific file-suffix)
4. Copy Finder Items

This works like a charm. But all files are copied in the same root destination folder. I need to keep the the sub folder structure. For Example:

```
sourceFolder
    subfolderA
        fileA.jpg
        fileB.xls
        fileC.xls
    subfolderB
        fileC.jpg
        fileD.xls
        fileE.xls
```

Expected result (filter for file suffix .xls):

```
destinationFolder
    subfolderA
        fileB.xls
        fileC.xls
    subfolderB
        fileD.xls
        fileE.xls
```

Current result:

```
destinationFolder
    fileB.xls
    fileC.xls
    fileD.xls
    fileE.xls
```

**Update**

I'm a developer. So a shell or AppleScript will be also accepted. :)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

```
rsync -avh --include='*/' --include='*.xls' --exclude='*' path/to/sourceFolder/ path/to/destinationFolder
```

Note the `/` at the end of the source path, it's *important*. This solution would add all empty directories, if you don't want them, look at the option `--prune-empty-dirs`.

With brace expansion you can actually include more filetypes at once, rather than having

```
--include='*.xls' --include='*.pdf' --include='*.txt'
```

you can use

```
--include='*.'{xls,pdf,txt}
```

Comment: great. ty! i will test and come back to it.

Comment: You can add all the options you want, the important part is the includes–excludes: include all directories (necessary for recursivity) and all `.xls` files, then exclude everythingn else. If you want more things like `--delete` add them to your command.

Answer (score 1):

I end up with a shell script, that works as requested:

```
$ find ./sourceFolder -name "*.xls*" -type f -print0 | xargs -0 -I '{}' /usr/bin/rsync -avR "{}" "./destinationFolder/"
```

Comment: `rsync -avh --include='*/' --include='*.xls' --exclude='*' sourceFolder/ destinationFolder`? With brace expansion you can actually include more filetypes `--include='*.'{xls,pdf,txt}`.

Comment: @Manuel ty! Any advantages / disadvantages of your solution?

Comment: That you don't concatenate through pipes, you just call `rsync` once with the appropiate flags.

Answer (score 0):

In a shell script you can use mkbom to make a BOM (bill of materials) file that contains a list of files that you want to copy.  Then you can use the ditto command with the --bom option to copy only files listed in the BOM file.

Comment: ty! Any advantages / disadvantages of your solution?